# Python: How can I check if an item in a list contains a string within an elif statement where two conditions must be met?

Tags: python, string, pandas, list, append

I'm making a scraper in python that executes a search, then opens each link in the search and makes a list of everything within a strong tag.

Then it append the list to a Dataset. Not all of the pages are the same so I am organizing them according to how many strong tags and in some cases if a particular tag contains one or more words. I need both conditions to be met in order for the contents of the strong tag to go the right column.

The code works but is bulky, and I'm trying to work on making clean code.

```
    for a in addr:
        driver.get(a)
        print(a)

        WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "_errorElement_")))
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

        columns = ['Business Name', 'Control Number', 'Business Type', 'Business Status', 'NAICS Code', 'NAICS Sub Code',
                   'Principal Office Address', 'Date of Formation/ Registration Date', 'State of Formation/ Jurisdiction',
                   'Last Registration Year', 'Dissolved Date', 'Registered Agent', 'Registered Agent Address', 'County']

        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
        strong = []
        for strong_tag in soup.find_all('strong'):
            strong.append(str(strong_tag.text))

        if len(strong) == 14:
            values = [strong[0], strong[1], strong[2], strong[3], strong[4], strong[5], strong[6], strong[7], strong[8],
                      strong[9], strong[10], strong[11], strong[12], strong[13]]
        elif len(strong) == 6:
            values = [strong[0], '', '', 'Name Reservation', '', '', strong[3], strong[1], '', '', '', strong[2], '', '']

        elif len(strong) == 13 and "Active" in str(strong[3]):
            values = [strong[0], strong[1], strong[2], strong[3], strong[4], strong[5], strong[6], strong[7], strong[8],
                      strong[9], '', strong[10], strong[11],strong[12]]
#the above code appears to be correct for 13 length active compliance Domestic LLC( and possibly active owes current year)
```

The following 5 elif statements are what i'm trying to combine. I'm not sure how to check if an item in a list contains any of the 5 words while also checking the length of the list.

```
 elif len(strong) == 13 and "Admin" in str(strong[3]):
        values = [strong[0], strong[1], strong[2], strong[3], strong[4], '', strong[5], strong[6], strong[7], strong[8],
                  strong[9], strong[10], strong[11], strong[12]]
    elif len(strong) == 13 and "Abandoned" in str(strong[3]):
        values = [strong[0], strong[1], strong[2], strong[3], strong[4], '', strong[5], strong[6], strong[7], strong[8],
                 strong[9], strong[10], strong[11], strong[12]]
    elif len(strong) == 13 and "Withdrawn" in str(strong[3]):
        values = [strong[0], strong[1], strong[2], strong[3], strong[4], '', strong[5], strong[6], strong[7], strong[8],
                  strong[9], strong[10], strong[11], strong[12]]
    elif len(strong) == 13 and "Dissolved" in str(strong[3]):
        values = [strong[0], strong[1], strong[2], strong[3], strong[4], '', strong[5], strong[6], strong[7], strong[8],
                 strong[9], strong[10], strong[11], strong[12]]
    elif len(strong) == 13 and "Terminated" in str(strong[3]):
        values = [strong[0], strong[1], strong[2], strong[3], strong[4], '', strong[5], strong[6], strong[7], strong[8],
                  strong[9], strong[10], strong[11], strong[12]]

    elif len(strong) == 12:
        values = [strong[0], strong[1], strong[2], strong[3], strong[4], '', strong[5], strong[6], strong[7], strong[8],
                  '', strong[9], strong[10], strong[11]]
    else:
        values = [strong[0], '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
        print("WARNING! New values length...")
    df = df.append(pd.Series(values, index=columns), ignore_index=True)
    df2 = df2.append(df)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Comment: I'm not working with DataFrame so I can not help. However, the condition `len(strong) == 13` in the second part of the code is repeated unnecessarily many times. Use once `if len(strong) == 13:` and below it other conditional conditions such as: `if "Dissolved" in str(strong[3]):` .... `if "Terminated" in str(strong[3]):` ...... etc.

Comment: I also noticed that the variable `values` in the second part of the source code are the same (under the condition `len(strong) == 13`). At the beginning of the test conditions, you can populate a temporary variable, such as `values_tmp` with these values and then assign this temporary `values_tmp` to the required variable: `values = values_tmp`. The source code will be cleaner but slowed by one extra line, which is always done at the beginning of the tests (even if no condition is met).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `in` the other way around, you want to check if `strong[3]` is `in` the array `['Admin', 'Abandoned', ...]`:

```
l = ['Admin', 'Abandoned', 'Withdrawn', 'Dissolved', 'Terminated']
if len(strong) == 13 and strong[3] in l:
    values = strong[:5] + [''] + strong[5:]
elif len(strong) == 12:
    values = strong[:5] + [''] + strong[5:9] + [''] + strong[9:]
else:
    values = [strong[0]] + ['']*12
```

P.S. And you can also combine elements when assigning to `values` to make it more concise

Comment: that worked! thanks for the tip about combining elements too.

Answer (score 0):

The inside checks are redundant, I will suggest you to add a length condition outside and when that condition is accomplished, then met the following requirements inside as example:

```
if len(strong) == 13:
   # All the flow comming here has a list of length 13
   if "Dissolved" in strong[3]:
      # Do whatever
      pass
   elif ...:
      ...
elif len(strong) == 12:
    ...
```

This way it's more understandable.